# Chromium: "This version of Chrome is no longer supported" - linux mint

Tags: chrome

I'm using Chromium Version 34.0.1847.116 Built on Ubuntu 13.10, running on LinuxMint 16 (260972)

Whenever I log into a Google app, I get the error "This version of Chrome is no longer supported. Please upgrade to a supported browser."

[image: Annoying message about version no longer supported]

It appears that version 34 is the current one in the mint repositories.  Therefore, I tried installing chromium version 37 from the Ubuntu repositories (along with a couple dependencies), yet when I would launch chromium from the command line, it would still open version 34.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to fix this error message?

Comment: I've got the same issue - did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Yep, it was to update linux Mint

Comment: I am running Chromium Version 37 on Debian Wheezy and I am having the same problem. Googling around it seems people are having similar issues with Google apps in IE on Windows :) . No solution though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because problem was solved by OP by updating the OS to a supported version

Comment: @Stephen Harris, _because problem was solved by OP by updating the OS to a supported version_. Where and when did the OP ever say that?

Comment: I don't mind if the question is migrated to for example superuser, but I insist that the question itself is highly valuable!

Comment: @Henke it was in the comments; "Yep, it was to update linux Mint – virtualxtc Dec 29 '14 at 19:25"

Comment: My bad. Not sure how I could miss that? If this question will not be reopened, I might post it again (not identical). Probably not in _this_ forum/site though.

Comment: @Henke I’m not sure reopening *this* question would be all that useful — the only answer now would be rather generic (upgrade Chromium). If you have specific circumstances which make it complicated to upgrade, that would be sufficient grounds to open a new question (even here), and would help you get a useful answer.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt. Actually I already have an answer. So what I am interested in doing is to ask the question (again) and then answering it myself. But it's fine, I can do that at the superuser site, or _maybe_ at https://webapps.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Henke good. If it’s not Unix/Linux-specific, then yes, SU would be more appropriate!